# Rewriting a proxy script URL

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I've been struggling for days now trying to figure this out, or if it is even possible, but basically I have a PHP proxy script running on an Apache server and I wish to rewrite the URL's such that you can't see that a proxy script is in use. For example:

http://www.domain-one.com/miniProxy.php/http://www.domain-two.com/about-us

Would look like:

http://www.domain-one.com/about-us

The proxy script is only being used to access a single domain, so domain-two.com can be hard-coded into the rewrite rule if need be. Is this even possible within the bounds of mod_rewrite rules? If so, can anyone help with what the regex might look like for something like this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use a href tag.

```
<a href="http://www.your_proxy_code">http://www.domain-one.com/about-us</a>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question because you would still see the long URL in the address bar after clicking the link. It needs to be some kind of mod_rewrite rule if what I'm trying to do is even possible. Thanks though.